# SQL Server 2008 modify data type of table column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unique-constraint

I need to modify the data type of a table column which is considered to be done via the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE QUANTITIES_NEW ALTER COLUMN VERSION_NEW VARCHAR(12);
```

Unfortunately I go an error (German)

```
Meldung 5074, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 1
Das Objekt-Objekt 'UQ_QUANTITIES_NAME_VERSION' ist vom Spalte-Objekt 'VERSION_NEW' abhängig.
Meldung 4922, Ebene 16, Status 9, Zeile 1
Fehler bei ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN VERSION_NEW, da mindestens ein Objekt auf diese Spalte zugreift.
```

which can be translated to:

```
The object-object 'UQ_QUANTITIES_NAME_VERSION' depends on the column object 'VERSION_NEW'.
Failure at ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN VERSION_NEW, because this column is accessed by one or more columns.
```

I assumed that the unique constraint isn't disabled. Therfore I executed the statement

```
ALTER TABLE QUANTITIES  NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
;
```

too. But still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DROP the associated CONSTRAINT. If you explode your tables, in the section constraints you'll find a constraint linked to your field. Drop it. After you can change your field type

Comment: Is there really no way to disable the constraint and afterwards enabale it. Because if I delete it I have to add it again.

Comment: IHMO, no way. Because in the constraint are stored some field information, like DEFAULT value.

Comment: Since the DDL statements are auto generated by a program, I need to know the details about the UniqueConstraint (e.g. the column names), because I want to get the same Constraint generated by the program. Is there a query to retrieve that info? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: select dc.name as [Constraint Name], dc.definition, so.name as [Table]
from sys.default_constraints dc
left join dbo.sysobjects so
on dc.parent_object_id = so.id
and so.xtype = 'u'
and so.name = 'your_table'
order by so.name

Comment: or try this: Try this: select t.name [table], c.name [column], d.name [constraint]
from sys.default_constraints d
join sys.tables t
on t.object_id = d.parent_object_id
join sys.columns c
on c.object_id = t.object_id
and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
where t.name = 'your_table'

Comment: No, ... both cases I just get back an empty result. As far I know, the unique constraints are kept in sys.key_constraint. Is there a way to join that table with dbo.sysobjects ?

Comment: select * from sys.key_constraints k
join sysobjects obj
on k.object_id = obj.id   you can try too k.parent_object_id

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally I got the solution which is:
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu
WHERE ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'CONSTRAINT_NAME'
;